# How to get real time feed to all the follower in node application

Tags: node.js, mongoose, socket.io, publish-subscribe, node-redis

I am developing Social network type of application in node.js and MongoDB. 
I want to add a functionality such as - 
If user A has followed user B then when user B post something it should automatically come to user A on his wall!

**Approach 1**- This is what I have research till now 
Create a channel of user B and all the other user subscribe to that channel and when user B post something then emit that with socket.io on all the subscribers.
so for this approach, we are thinking to create a channel when the new user signup every time.

**But the problem is** -
is this feasible approach as for how do I know which channel is which user or is there a way to store the channel in MongoDB.
if I create too many channels will that crash my server?

**Approach 2 -**

Another Approach that I have got is

Look up the followers of the source user in your database.
And emit feeds to all the followers using socket.io 
How to scale this if I have got 100 followers of each user and when everytime user post, will searching in a Database creates an overhead.
Using Redis caching would be better to store followers?
And instead of checking the followers-
find that from Redis and emit the msg using socket.io

**Approach 3 -**

I have heard the name of Redis pub/sub but not able to find how it will work in my application.

Please suggest some best standards for creating something like this! 
And if above approaches are fine can you pls suggest me the flow for that or how do I create a code for that!

I would be great if you provide me an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `Approach 2`, but you must create a queue (redis queue or rabbitMQ) to do that.
I mean when you create a post, it must push to queue to push message to 100, 1000 follower in your DB.

Comment: And to make this optimal do I store followers in redis? So that every time there is no need of checking the Backend Database ??

Comment: No need, because we don't need to send message immediately to followers, so you can run the job in queue to do that. just query from DB.